# Define an array as having a mandatory value, plus optional others

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do something like this:

I have a `Student` type and `Teacher` type, they are similar, except that all teachers always have the `"staffroom_access"` privilege. Students can optionally have this privilege.

I've tried to do this as below with this line:

```
privileges: Role[] extends ["staffroom_access"]
```

But this gives me:

```
Property 'privileges' of exported interface has or is using private name ''.(4033)
```

Full code:

```
type Role = "staffroom_access" | "sportsroom_access"; 

type Teacher = {
    name: string; 
    privileges: Role[] extends ["staffroom_access"]; //Property 'privileges' of exported interface has or is using private name ''.(4033)
}

type Student = {
    name: string; 
    privileges: Role[]; 
}

const mrJones: Teacher = {
    name: "Mr Jones",
    privileges: [] //Should error
}; 

const mrSmith: Teacher = {
    name: "Mr Smith",
    privileges: ["staffroom_access"] //Should be Ok 
};
```

How would I achieve the functionality that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rest elements in tuple types as follows:

```
type Teacher = {
    name: string; 
    privileges: ["staffroom_access", ...Role[]];
}
```

This will give you the exact behavior you want.

Comment: Me neither! Had to look it up :)